# Univariate, binary ``loess`` vs ``lowess``

Tags: r, loess

Consider the following data:

```
probs <- seq(0,0.3, by=0.001)

targets <- sapply(probs, function(p){
  sample(c(0,1),size=1,prob = c(1-p,p))
})
```

Using `loess` I can then graph the smoothed "targets" values as estimates of the probabilities:

```
require(magrittr)
loess(targets~probs,span=0.3) %>% predict %>% {plot(. ~ probs)}
```

However, I am not able to do that using `lowess`, despite whatever `f` value is chosen:

```
lowess(x = probs, y = targets, f = 0.01) %>% with(plot(y ~ x))
```

**My questions:** why do the results differ? Is there any way to achieve the same output from `lowess` that would match the `loess` one?

As per numerous threads on SO, it would seem that for univariate cases loess and lowess should match.

---

*Unrelated side note:* why won't I use `loess` then? The goal is to understand the differences between `lowess` and `loess`. Furthermore, I would like to reapply the results using Python's `statsmodels`, which, to my knowledge, provide only `lowess`.

Comment: There is a pretty good discussion here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/161069/difference-between-loess-and-lowess. The `lowess` function tries to fit sliding linear regressions but the `loess` function uses `degree=2` polynomials by default. If you just plot `plot(targets~probs)` it's clear your data does not really have a linear trend. You have a binomial distribution. How exactly do you want to interpret these smoothed curves?

Comment: @MrFlick Thanks, will look into it. The interpretation is related to [package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/heatmapFit/index.html) and [paper](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/political-analysis/article/abs/assessing-fit-quality-and-testing-for-misspecification-in-binarydependent-variable-models/3BC15DBD2114F6E0A0BAA05AE6C7D658). A smoothed curve of a "calibrated" model will envelope the diagonal of ``{plot(. ~ probs)}`` plot.  Do I understand correctly that there is no way to specify ``degree = 2`` for ``lowess``?

Comment: `lowess(x, y = NULL, f = 2/3, iter = 3, delta = 0.01 * diff(range(x)))`   vs. `loess(formula, data, weights, subset, na.action, model = FALSE,
      span = 0.75, enp.target, degree = 2,
      parametric = FALSE, drop.square = FALSE, normalize = TRUE,
      family = c("gaussian", "symmetric"),
      method = c("loess", "model.frame"),
      control = loess.control(...), ...)`    "Choose wisely"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's easier to generate your random sample using `rbinom`:

```r
probs <- seq(0, 0.3, by = 0.001)

set.seed(1)
targets <- rbinom(301, 1, probs)
```

The `loess` smooth looks like this:

```r
est_loess <- loess(targets ~ probs, span = 0.3) |> predict()

plot(probs, est_loess, type = "l")
```

[image]

If you want a similar result from `lowess`, try setting `iter` to 0:

```r
est_lowess <- lowess(x = probs, y = targets, f = 0.2, iter = 0) 

plot(est_lowess, type = "l")
```

[image]

In either case, be very careful when smoothing probabilities like this. You run the risk of having nonsensical values outside the 0-1 range. Where possible, you should convert to odds, smooth these, then convert back to probabilities. One way to achieve this is to use `gam` with `family = "binomial"`

```r
library(mgcv)

est_gam <- gam(targets ~ s(probs, k = 100, m = 1), gamma = 0.9,
               family = binomial) |>
  predict(type = "response")

plot(probs, est_gam, type = "l", ylim = c(0, 0.3))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-09-06 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>